# regex - find XML tag that occurs together with another tag value

Tags: regex

Let's say I have XML:
`<Customer><CustomerType>Business</CustomerType><CreditRating>Good</CreditRating></Customer>`
`<Customer><CustomerType>Residential</CustomerType><CreditRating>Good</CreditRating></Customer>`

and I want to change all the Credit Ratings for the Residential consumers from Good to Bad.

What regex search term can I use to find (and therefore replace) the CreditRating tag only when this occurs within a customer record with a residential Customer Type?

I know I can use:
`<Customer>.*?<CustomerType>Residential.*?</Customer>` to match a whole record Residential customer record but I only want to match the CreditRating tag within the Customer Record so I can do a search and replace.

Thanks a lot,

:-)

Comment: Add exact programming tags which you tried and post what have tried?

Comment: Trying to parse XML with regex is usually a bad idea... XSLT or XQuery would be better choices imo.

Comment: Fatal Error - in the actual XML the Customer Type is a subnode, so not sure how to match this in XQuery.. :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easy (and safe) in XSLT...

**XML Input** (wrapped in `<Customers>` to be well-formed)

```
<Customers>
    <Customer>
        <CustomerType>Business</CustomerType>
        <CreditRating>Good</CreditRating>
    </Customer>
    <Customer>
        <CustomerType>Residential</CustomerType>
        <CreditRating>Good</CreditRating>
    </Customer>
</Customers>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Customer[CustomerType='Residential']/CreditRating">
        <CreditRating>Bad</CreditRating>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output XML**

```
<Customers>
   <Customer>
      <CustomerType>Business</CustomerType>
      <CreditRating>Good</CreditRating>
   </Customer>
   <Customer>
      <CustomerType>Residential</CustomerType>
      <CreditRating>Bad</CreditRating>
   </Customer>
</Customers>
```